# if this.className.match Ajax complete

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to determine whether the user has clicked confirm or deny link.

If confirm... when complete:

```
idurl = '<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/profile.php?userid='+id+'';
if (idurl == window.location.href) {
     window.location = idurl;
}
```

else if deny:

```
parent.slideUp(300,function() {});
$('.friend-count').load('<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/friendrequestscount.php').fadeIn("fast");
```

The following script is working great without:

```
complete: function() {
        if (this.className.match("confirm")){
```

How can i check if its the confirmfriend.php that has completed?

```
<script>
   $('.friendaction').click(function() {
       var id = this.getAttribute('data-userid');
       var requestto = this.getAttribute('data-requestto'),
       parent = $(this).closest("li"),
           url = this.className.match("confirm") 
              ? "confirmfriend.php" 
              : "removefriend.php", 
           liReference = $(this).parent();
       $.ajax(url + "?userid=" + id, {
           complete: function() {
            if (this.className.match("confirm")){
                      idurl = '<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/profile.php?userid='+id+'';
                      if (idurl == window.location.href) {
                          window.location = idurl;
                      }
            } else {
                    parent.slideUp(300,function() {});
                    $('.friend-count').load('<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/friendrequestscount.php').fadeIn("fast");
            }
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $('.friendaction').click(function() {
       var id = this.getAttribute('data-userid');
       var requestto = this.getAttribute('data-requestto'),
       parent = $(this).closest("li"),
           url = this.className.match("confirm") 
              ? "confirmfriend.php" 
              : "removefriend.php", 
           liReference = $(this).parent();
       $.ajax(url + "?userid=" + id, {
           complete: function() {
            if (url == "confirmfriend.php"){
                      idurl = '<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/profile.php?userid='+id+'';
                      if (idurl == window.location.href) {
                          window.location = idurl;
                      }
            } else {
                    parent.slideUp(300,function() {});
                    $('.friend-count').load('<?php echo $siteUrl ?>/friendrequestscount.php').fadeIn("fast");
            }
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```